# Markov's Inequality and convergence in probability

Tags: probability, convergence, probability-inequalities

Theorem: (Markov's Inequality):
Let x be a non-negative random variable. Then, for all $b >0$

$P[x \geq b] \leq \frac{E(x)}{b}$.

#################

Suppose that $ x_{t}$ is a non-negative random variable, where $t=1....n $. By using the above theorem, we obtain that

$P[x_{t}  \geq n] \leq \frac{E(x_{t})}{n}$,  for all  $n>0$.

Is the following true? if this is not true, would you please explain why?

$x_{t}=O_{p}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$, where p means  probability upper bound.

$\sum_{t=1}^{n} x_{t} = O_{p}\left(1\right)$, where p means  probability upper bound.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $O_P$ does not mean convergence in probability. It represents an in probability upper bound. And neither of your statements are true. If $E[x_t] < \infty$ then $x_t = O_P(1)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!